# Nutch solr index is failing

Tags: solr, nutch

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa), Java openjdk version "1.8.0_275", Solr 8.8.0 and Nutch 1.18

I ran a nutch crawl successfully.  When I run this command to index my data into Solr:

`sudo -E bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/eaccpf/ crawl/eaccpf/crawldb -linkdb crawl/eaccpf/linkdb crawl/eaccpf/segments/*`

I get this result:

```
Segment dir is complete: crawl/eaccpf/segments/20210225102713.
Indexer: starting at 2021-02-25 15:47:11
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Killed
```

Any suggestions?  What does "Killed" mean?  I know that there are a lot of config files for solr and nutch.  I have tried to follow all the documentation that I have found online to set this up and I have scrutinized all those config files.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Killed" - please look into the system log for the reason. Remarks: (1) the command "solrindex" is deprecated and is replaced by "index". (2) There is no need to run the command using "sudo". (3) "all the documentation": please follow the [official tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial)

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  This command worked:

```bin/nutch index crawl/eaccpf/crawldb -linkdb crawl/eaccpf/linkdb crawl/eaccpf/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone```

But I don't see anything on my Solr Admin screen.  Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: (1) look at the logs (console output and hadoop.log) - the number of indexed documents is logged "Indexing m/n documents". (2) same for the Solr logs. (3) by default the Solr core is named "nutch", looks like you want to name it "eaccpf" which needs a change in the index-writers.xml.

Comment: Thanks. I changed index-writers.xml like so:
```<param name="url" value="http://localhost:8983/solr/eaccpf"/>```
But now when I index to solr I get the output below. It's the specs for SolrIndexWriter.  Any idea why?  I see the same thing in the hadoop log. ```│url         │Defines the fully qualified URL of Solr into which data should be  indexed.│http://localhost:8983/solr/eaccpf│```

Comment: This line belongs to a table which shows the configuration of all active index writers. The counters logging the number of indexed documents are logged below the table.

Comment: This is the end of the hadoop log: 

```2021-03-04 11:17:19,038 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
2021-03-04 11:17:19,053 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: finished at 2021-03-04 11:17:19, elapsed: 00:00:05```

Can I assume that nothing was indexed?  Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, if no counters are shown, nothing is indexed. Possible reasons: no pages successfully crawled in the indexed segments, all URLs filtered away, etc. But the reason is difficult to figure out when only looking at 3 log lines.

Comment: I think you are correct.  I think the problem is in this step; ```bin/nutch fetch $s1```.  It takes 1.5 hours to run but I suspect that it is not returning any results.  It's hard to tell from the logs.  Do you know what I should look for that would indicate failure?

Comment: The logs (look into the hadoop.log) shows all counters of the fetch job, including the number of successfully fetched pages in the group "FetcherStatus". It's important to verify also the counters of other jobs, e.g. the job "updatedb" logs how many successfully fetched pages (status "db_fetched") are in the CrawlDb. It's mandatory to read the logs in case of errors or unexpected behavior. In addition, inspect CrawlDb and segments using the tools "readdb" resp. "readseg". And I recommend to analyze potential errors first with smaller subsets (for example, a crawl with 2 cycles and 10 seeds).